# Change intellij/android studio tool window quick access shortcuts

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

Is it possible to change the quick access shortcut numbers for a tool window?

i.e. the numbers next to a tool window name, used by the keyboard shortcut to toggle the window, talked about [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/manipulating-the-tool-windows.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yep. They are listed in **Keymap**. <kbd>MainMenu -> View -> ToolWindows</kbd>.

*P.S.:* Idea has a nice `Find by shortcut` function in Keymap settings page, I used it, to answer your question.

[image: Screenshot of icon location]

Comment: Cool thanks! Seems like these shortcuts are a bit messed up in android studio but I think I can change most of them.

Comment: @athor If you used IntelliJ idea before, you can import your previous settings. If you used eclipse, there is nice Eclipse-like profile already prebuilt in idea. Look at keymaps dropdown. Anyway, Idea is greatly customizable, just dig deeper=)

Comment: My "Tool Windows" option is not expandable. Anyone have any idea why?

Comment: Issue was resolved, the tool windows options were under the "Other" section.

Comment: FYI, I have found (at least with 2018.2.*) that the tab names are not prefixed with the number until you restart (though you can use the shortcut right away).

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio, you can change the Keymap this way:

`Preferences` -> `Keymap`

Then open `Tool Windows`.  You may need to scroll down to see all the options.
[image]

Right-click on the element you want to assign a new key-stroke.  Select `Add Keyboard Shortcut`.  Make sure that the rectangle with a plus in it is selected (use your mouse) and press the key-stroke that you want for this item.

[image]

Android Studio will warn you if that key-stroke is already assigned.  Click `OK` to reassign that key-stroke to the item.  It'll warn you *one more time* that you will need to remove the previous assignment for that key-stroke.  Click `Remove` to proceed.  You should see the updated keystroke in the right-most column.